# How to run tests in a specific order?

Tags: quarkus

How can I run quarkus tests in a specific order?
Usually we have the @InSequence annotation (from arquillian IIRC) which we could achieve this.

But I didn't find anything similar for Quarkus on "org.junit.jupiter.api" package provided by quarkus-junit5.

It will run in a aleatory order, I tried to use org.junit.jupiter.api.Order togheter with @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class) annotation, but seems not to work.

Is there a way to achieve proper test execution order with QuarkusTest?

Comment: I don't think JUnit 5 has support for ordered tests

Answer (score 3):

Quarkus tests are simply JUnit 5 tests.

See [2.9. Test Execution Order](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order) for examples on how to use **@TestMethodOrder**.